# Git pull seems to work but doesn't change anything

Tags: git, github, merge, fetch, pull

I tried to use the command `pull` to make a pull from a remote repository on github to a local directory. The output seems correct, however, nothing happens.

My computer is a Mac Book Air M1 2020, 16 GB.

When I add a new remote repository on terminal apparently it works. This is how I do it:

```
cd "local-dir-source"
git init
git remote add origin "remote-repo-source.git"
git remote -v
```

and this is the output:

```
origin  "remote-repo-source.git" (fetch)
origin  "remote-repo-source.git" (push)
```

And, when I try to pull, the output on terminal is correct:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 93, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (93/93), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
remote: Total 93 (delta 26), reused 74 (delta 16), pack-reused 0
Unpacking: 100% (93/93), 20.18 KiB | 148.00 KiB/s, done.
From "remote-repo-source"
 * [new branch]    master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]    testing    -> origin/testing
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Specify the branch you want to merge by.
See git-pull(1) for more details.

    git pull <remoto> <branch>

If you want to set tracking information for this branch you can do it with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

However, on the local directory, files in the remote repo do not appear.
I also tried with `fetch` and `merge`, and the problem is the same. They apparently work well, but nothing happens.

Comment: `And, when I try to pull` ... what exact command did you use to pull, and also, from which branch?

Comment: The command used was simply `git pull`. The problem, like you noticed, was the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After these steps:

```
cd "local-dir-source"
git init
git remote add origin "remote-repo-source.git"
```

You have a local repository *without a branch*. `git pull` fetches remote branches for you, but since you don't have a local branch, git doesn't know which remote branch to checkout. You can manually checkout a branch so git will present your files:

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I just forgot that command.

Comment: @LBB04 If you find this answer helpful, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to create a new repository locally from a remote right? In that case you could just to a [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

`git clone <repo>.git`